# Javascript code giving error

Tags: javascript

```
// Check if the user is ready to play!
var userAnswer = prompt("Do you want to race Bieber on stage?")
console.log("Suddenly, Bieber stops and says, 'Who wants to race me?'")
if userAnswer === "yes" {
console.log("You and Bieber start racing. It's neck and neck! You win by a shoelace!");
} else {
console.log("Oh no! Bieber shakes his head and sings 'I set a pace, so I can race without pacing.'");
}
```

I'm trying to do this: If userAnswer is yes, print out "You and Bieber start racing. It's neck and neck! You win by a shoelace!

Otherwise, print out: "Oh no! Bieber shakes his head and sings I set a pace, so I can race without pacing.

But it gives me a syntax error.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: `if(userAnswer === 'yes'){}`  You need parenthesis with an `if` statement.

Comment: welcome to Stackoverflow. However, when asking questions make sure to report all the details; when you have a problem that involves errors, those errors should be included in your post so that people can help determine the problem without having to run your code. In this case, you got a syntax error, and those generally come with a line number, so I strongly suspect you could have found the problem entirely without our help by simply following the details that the JS console gave you. This is also a SO policy: first follow the clues you get. Only if that fails might SO be a good idea.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is with this line:

```
if userAnswer === "yes" {
```

you need to change that line to:

```
if (userAnswer === "yes") {
```

So your whole code should read:

```
var userAnswer = prompt("Do you want to race Bieber on stage?")
console.log("Suddenly, Bieber stops and says, 'Who wants to race me?'")
if (userAnswer === "yes") {
    console.log("You and Bieber start racing. It's neck and neck! You win by a shoelace!");
} else {
    console.log("Oh no! Bieber shakes his head and sings 'I set a pace, so I can race without pacing.'");
}
```

Hope this helps.